# Particle を between nouns

Tags: translation, meaning, particle-を

So there I am again, asking a question from the book "Sword Art Online 1".

This time it's about the sentence: またの名`を`≪ソードアート・オンライン≫。

What is the meaning of を in this case?

Comment: Is ショー度 a rare typo for ソード?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for letting me know - I'll correct it .

Comment: How are your two questions related?  If they are not related, please do not cramp them into one question.

Comment: They're not really... I just thought it'd be easier than posting twice... if you say so though..

Comment: (1) Please consider from the viewpoint of those who answer your questions.  Why should they be forced to answer the two questions at the same time?  Personally, I would rather choose to answer neither if I think that I am being forced to do something without a good reason.

Comment: (2) Just in case, I am not suggesting that you post one question after another.  If you do so, you may be viewed as a free rider.  But you cannot avoid being viewed as a free rider by just cramping several questions into one post.

Comment: I asked about a similar example of `NをN` once, and Chocolate suggested it was ellipsis for 「・・・と言う」 or [・・・と呼ぶ」 or such.  I think (but don't know) that this is the same thing.

Comment: More references found via Google: [an explanation on another forum](http://forums.delphiforums.com/n/mb/message.asp?webtag=nihongoforum&msg=97.1) and two entries on Weblio: [one entry](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86) and [another](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I'm in no way trying to force anyone to answer both questions. I appreciate even the slightest hints. In my point of view, posting each question separately would cause a lot of mess and in-organization.
As for the "free-rider" term, I don't believe I'm in the position to answer other's questions yet. That's why I'm still learning and asking questions rather than taking the risk of going wrong and possibly misleading other people. In a community like this, users should contribute what they **know**, rather than what they **need** to answer.

Comment: @snailplane - thanks. That's probably it.
In the first link you posted, the Japanese comes out as gibberish, is it the same for you?

Comment: You are missing the point of my comments.  Answering other questions is not the only way to “pay back,” and I am not complaining for not answering other people’s questions.  Please make efforts to ask good questions.  For example, leaving a half-done edit (which snailplane cleaned up for you) is not appreciated.

Comment: I was on a mobile phone, and therefore limited in my ability to edit. Furthermore, how do **you** define a good question? My question is completely fine according to http://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask. What're you're suggesting is a great recipe for pure mess and in-organization, in my opinion. Plus, all of my recent questions are from a book I'm reading, and therefore, are in fact related. By the way, in the same way, I could essentially say your comments are off-topic, and therefore not "good enough", but I won't since I appreciate you and your honest critique. So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The particle `を` is a 格助詞{かくじょし} ("case particle").  Normally, a case particle marks a noun or noun phrase to show its relationship to the predicate (such as a verb or an adjective), or to another noun or noun phrase. Specifically, the particle `を` marks the [accusative case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case). This means that it marks the *direct object* of a verb.

Therefore, we would expect to find just such a verb in this sentence.  Since there *is* no verb, we can assume this is an example of [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).
Something has been left out, and as the reader, it's our job to guess what it is.

Searching on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&q=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92) and 
[Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92) for `またの名を` 
reveals that it is a common phrase meaning "also known as".  The full phrase
`またの名を〜と言う` is [also listed on Weblio](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86)
 and appears to be relatively common, so it's reasonable to guess that the elided phrase is `と言う`.  (You could also guess that it's `と呼ぶ` or something similar; it doesn't change the meaning very much.)

Therefore, we can interpret your sentence as the following:

> またの名を≪ソードアート・オンライン≫と言う。

So what does `を` mean in this sentence?  It has the same function it usually does, which is marking the direct object of a verb.